# (Excel) Use range and criteria by column and sum_range by row

Tags: excel, sum

This is a sample value for my Excel file.

```
AA | 1 | 2 | 3
BB | 2 | 3 | 1
CC | 3 | 5 | 4
```

When I choose **AA** using the **SUMIF()** function, it only returns the first value. How do I get the sum of a whole row based on the selected cell in a column?

```
AA | 6
BB | 6
CC | 12
```

EDIT:  Output for AA change to 6 (typo)

This is the formula that I am using:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:A4, B1, $B$2:$D$2)
```

Comment: Post the formula that you tried with please

Comment: Can you post the formula you are using. How are you "selecting a cell"?

Comment: @pnuts That was my mistake. Corrected!

Comment: Updated. Formula included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Instead of using SUMIF(), I used SUMPRODUCT().

```
= SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$4=B1) * $B$2:$D$4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `AA` is in A1 (and also in A6) then in B6 and copied down to suit:

```
=SUM(1:1)
```